# Numpy TypeError for function

Tags: python, numpy

I have been implementing an algorithm that requires I take the average of vectors from a specific point to a set of other points and "unitise" it. As such, I use this function:

```
import numba
import numpy

def dist(a,b):
    return ((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)**0.5

@jit
def point_average(o, points):
     vectors = np.zeros((2,len(points)))
    for i in range(0,len(points)):
        vectors[0,i] = (points[i,0]-o[0])/dist(i,o)
        vectors[1,i] = (points[i,1]-o[1])/dist(i,o)
        vector = (np.sum(vectors[0]),np.sum(vectors[1]))
    d = dist(vector,(0,0))
    return (o[0]+vector[0]/d,o[1]+vector[1]/d)
```

However, when calling this function in a larger function called tree(), I get a TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isky\Documents\IT\Programs\SpaceColonisation.py", line 81, in <module>
    tree()
  File "C:\Users\Isky\Documents\IT\Programs\SpaceColonisation.py", line 67, in tree
    n = point_average(j, l)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Now, the statement on line 81 it dislikes is

```
n = point_average(j, l)
```

where "l" is a list of points and "j" is a point from  a list called "nodes", both represented as tuples like (x,y).

Why am I getting this error? Does numpy think that point_average() is an array and I am attempting to index it with tuples?

EDIT:

As helpfully pointed out, I should have included an MCVE, so here is one. I printed out the "j" and "l" so we have:

```
j = (0,0)
l = [np.array([ 40.79669845,  23.10185075]), np.array([  1.29143263, -25.70311497]), np.array([-10.31449425, -45.78984709]), np.array([  1.21100438,  32.65835732]), np.array([ 13.69990749,  13.11397896]), np.array([ 37.84780568,  27.06853658])]
print(point_average(j,l))
```

and that still produces the error.

Comment: Add sample case?

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try `print(point_average)` above the statement and see for yourself what Python thinks it is. :)

Comment: @NilsWerner, sorry! Updated it now, thanks.

Comment: @musically_ut yup, it does say function... (I was being silly.)

Comment: Also added dist(), which is referenced in point_average()

Comment: What do you expect the result of `dist(i,o)` to be, when `i` is an `int` and `o` is a `tuple`?

Comment: This was another error (i shouldn't have been an int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`points` is a `list` of `arrays`, not a 2D `array`. Hence you cannot do

```
points[i, 0]
```

you could only do

```
points[i][0]
```

Also, if you consequently use NumPy arrays instead of lists and arrays, you don't need Numba at all:

```
def point_average(o, points):
    vectors = (points - o) / numpy.linalg.norm(points - o, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    vector = np.sum(vectors, axis=0)
    d = numpy.linalg.norm(vector)
    return o + vector / d

j = np.zeros(2)
l = np.array([
    [ 40.79669845,  23.10185075],
    [  1.29143263, -25.70311497],
    [-10.31449425, -45.78984709],
    [  1.21100438,  32.65835732],
    [ 13.69990749,  13.11397896],
    [ 37.84780568,  27.06853658]
])
point_average(j, l)
```

Comment: Thanks! Just saying, my MVCE does not accurately reflect the rest of my program and so I still need to use Numba (both j and l change regularly).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but changing `j` and `l` still doesn't mean you have to implement the `for` loop yourself but can still use Numpy vectorization.